# Count views using django ratelimit per user

Tags: django

To limit form posts for some models in the front end I recently started using [django-ratelimit](https://github.com/jsocol/django-ratelimit). I want to **prevent misuse** by **limiting edits** to an acceptable amount.

I've got django-ratelimit working for POST actions on the form based on IP. I however would like to ratelimit the forms based on the authenticated user. It seems [keys](https://django-ratelimit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#ratelimit) argument can be used, but I just can't get my head around how it works. Anyone done this before using django-ratelimit? Or perhaps known of a better way to limit form submissions per user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to rate-limit based on the authenticated user i.e., request.user, you can use `user` as key

From official docs, here's the usage of key `user`

> 'user' - Use an appropriate value from request.user. Do not use with unauthenticated users.

Below is the example decorator:

```
@ratelimit(block=True, rate='1000/m', key='user' group='ext_api')
```

You can go through all the common options for key:

https://django-ratelimit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keys.html

Answer (score 0):

Below method can be useful for you

```
from django.db import models
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
import datetime, random

class RequestRateManager(models.Manager):
    def clean_expired(self):
        """Purges old entries from database.

        If you use max_value's greater than 600 (seconds, ten minutes),
        change the following line."""
        l_time = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(seconds = 600)
        self.get_query_set().filter(last_update__lt=l_time).delete()

class RequestRate(models.Model):
    """Implements a rate limit per IP.

    value is increased at every request by the amount the request specifies,
    which is meant to be the average number of seconds until the same
    request could be made again.

    value decreases at a rate of 1 per second until it is a 0.
    """
    user_id = models.IntFied(blank=True, null=True)
    last_update = models.DateTimeField()
    value = models.FloatField()

    objects = RequestRateManager()

    def update(self):
        this_update = datetime.datetime.now()
        td = this_update - self.last_update
        time_delta_sec = (float(td.days) * 3600.0 * 60.0 + float(td.seconds) +
            float(td.microseconds) / 1000000.0)
        self.value -= time_delta_sec
        if self.value < 0:
            self.value = 0
        self.last_update = this_update
    def request(self, seconds, max_value):
        self.update()
        if self.value + seconds < max_value:
            self.value += seconds
            self.save()
            return True
        else:
            self.save()
            return False

def limit(seconds, max_value, per_user=True, limit_exceeded_view=None,
        limit_exceeded_template='connection_limit_exceeded.html'):
    """Makes a rate-limiting decorator"""
    def default_limit_exceeded_view(*args, **kwargs):
        return render_to_response(limit_exceeded_template)
    limit_exceeded_view = limit_exceeded_view or default_limit_exceeded_view
    def decorator(view):
        def limited_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if random.random() < 0.05:
                RequestRate.objects.clean_expired()
            if per_user:
                ru = request.user.id
            else:
                ru = None
            (l,tmp) = RequestRate.objects.get_or_create(user_id=ru,
                defaults={ 'last_update': datetime.datetime.now(), 'value': 0 })
            if l.request(seconds, max_value):
                return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return limit_exceeded_view(*args, **kwargs)
        return limited_view
    return decorator


@limit(1,1)
def your_view(request):
  pass
```